# Trouble copying file while SSH'd into another computer to my local computer?

Tags: ssh, file-copy

I am ssh'd into a computer.  There is a file on the home directory I would like to copy to my local computer.  I tried running

```
scp readme brian@HomeLenovo:/home/Documents/cp_readme
```

where brian@HomeLenovo is my peronsal laptop, but I keep getting the error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname homelenovo: No address associated with hostname
lost connection
```

I assume this is because the computer I am ssh'd into doesn't "know" about my computer or what that hostname references - how can I resolve this without installing anything or making changes to the computer I am ssh'd into?

Comment: The usual approach is to issue `scp brian@remoteMachine:/path/readme /home/Documents/cp_readme` from your homeLenovo machine. You can also use fuse-mounts to make this process less burdensome.

Answer (score -1):

on your `HomeLenovo` laptop, type `ping HomeLenovo` and get its IP address.
For example it comes back and says 10.1.2.3.

Then from that other computer instead do

`scp readme brian@10.1.2.3:/home/brian/Documents/`

Or you may edit the local `/etc/hosts` file on that computer you are ssh'd in to provided you have root permission to do so.  Then add the line

```
10.1.2.3  HomeLenovo
```

and then from that computer it would then know how to resolve the hostname *HomeLenovo* to some ip address... because you manually told it what it was and then your original `scp` command using the hostname would work.

note: don't use 10.1.2.3.  I used that as an example.  Use the ip address that responds from HomeLenovo simply pinging itself, that's probably the easiest & fastest way to get that.

Comment: This assumes that HomeLenovo is a server and that it is in a local area network. There is no indication in the question that any of these are true.